# ExpressionTree as method parameter to accept any method

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I need to make a method that examines dynamically method delegate passed as a parameter. But I can't force expression trees to accept any method regardless of their signature.

This is my method (doesn't compile: `error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'method' to 'Delegate'` )

```
public void Examine<T>(Expression<Func<T, Delegate>> expression2)
{
   // examine expression tree to get method name (MethodInfo)
}
```

I want to invoke it this way:

```
Examine<Foo>(x => foo1.Test1);
Examine<Bar>(x => bar2.DifferentMethod2);
// etc, with other methods
```

where:

- class Foo has method: `bool Test1(int num)`
- class Bar has method: 'string DifferentMethod2(string a, string b)`
- and many others

How to achieve it?

Remark:

- I CAN'T use Func<> or Action<> as there will be many possible method signatures that need to be accepted with parameter types I will not have a reference to.

Comment: Have not tested it, but func or action with dynamic? quacks like a duck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have to use `Func` or `Action`, however you can use it on the caller side instead of the method side so you can still accept any type.

```
static void Main()
{
    Foo foo1 = null;
    Bar bar2 = null;
    Examine<Foo>(x => (Func<int,bool>)foo1.Test1);
    Examine<Bar>(x => (Func<string,string,string>)bar2.DifferentMethod2);
}
public static void Examine<T>(Expression<Func<T, Delegate>> expression2)
{
    // examine expression tree to get method name (MethodInfo)
}
```

This creates a expression like

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[SandboxConsole.Foo,System.Delegate]>(SandboxConsole.Foo $x) {
    (System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean]).Call .Constant<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>(Boolean Test1(Int32)).CreateDelegate(
        .Constant<System.Type>(System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean]),
        .Constant<SandboxConsole.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0>(SandboxConsole.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).foo1)
}
```

and

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[SandboxConsole.Bar,System.Delegate]>(SandboxConsole.Bar $x) {
    (System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]).Call .Constant<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>(System.String DifferentMethod2(System.String, System.String)).CreateDelegate(
        .Constant<System.Type>(System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]),
        .Constant<SandboxConsole.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0>(SandboxConsole.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).bar2)
}
```

for the two invocations.